# Request insufficient authentication scopes when running Spark-Job on dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run the spark job on the google dataproc cluster as

```
 gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster <cluster-name> \
--jar file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar \
--class org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount \
--arg1 \
--arg2 \
```

But the Job throws error

```
 (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.spark) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

How do I add the auth scopes to run the JOB?

Comment: Are you creating the Dataproc cluster (via gcloud dataproc clusters create) and attempting to run the Dataproc job (via gcloud dataproc jobs submit) from the same machine / shell? In general, your credentials need the CLOUD_PLATFORM OAuth to interact with Dataproc.

Comment: To elaborate on Angus's question, that also means if you're running the gcloud command from any GCE VM, then you needed to create the GCE VM with `--scopes cloud-platform` (see [gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using)). Same applies to if you're running the command from inside a Dataproc cluster; you'd use `gcloud dataproc clusters create --scopes cloud-platform`.

Comment: @Dennis Huo Could you possibly post that comment as an answer so this question may be closed? The only thing I would add is the recent addition of [gcloud alpha compute instances set-scopes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes) for correcting the scope of already existing GCE instances.

Comment: Done, thanks for pinging this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually if you're running into this error it's because of running gcloud from inside a GCE VM that's using [VM-metadata controlled scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes), since otherwise gcloud installed on a local machine will typically already be using broad scopes to include all GCP operations.

For Dataproc access, when creating the VM from which you're running gcloud, you need to specify `--scopes cloud-platform` from the CLI, or if creating the VM from the Cloud Console UI, you should select "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs":

[image: Cloud Console Create VM UI - Identity and API access]

As another commenter mentioned above, nowadays you can also [update scopes on existing GCE instances](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes) to add the CLOUD_PLATFORM scope.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to check the option for allowing the API access while creating the DataProc cluster. Then only you can submit the jobs to cluster using **gcloud dataproc jobs submit**
command[image]